# Removing area from stroked circle

Tags: adobe-illustrator, shapes, stroke

I've been trying to design a logo, however I can not figure out the simplest thing. I have two circles, with no fill and a stroke. I've added a white rectangle to "cut out" area of both the strokes, and lastly, the inner circle has an additional line added to make the letter "G". Since the white rectangle (black stroke added for viewing purposes) is there, when I export it as a .eps, it exports with the file... My question is, what is the easiest way to remove the area in the two circular strokes, so upon export, that area is transparent?

Image attached.
[image: G Circle Demo]

Comment: Hi Adam Blum, welcome to GD.SE! Have you tried using the path finder options?

Answer (score 0):

If the two circles you've got there are circles with strokes, you'll first need to expand them (Object > Expand). Then you can use the pathfinder, in this case merge will probably work best (Effect > Pathfinder > Merge). Delete the white box afterwards and you should have what you're looking for. Make sure you've got everything the way you want it before you expand though, it's harder to tweak things afterwards.

Comment: I usually make a copy of whatever I'm expanding before I start something like this and keep it off to the side for a while. Just in case I decide to go back.

Answer (score 0):

I would Recommend you to use Clipping mask for it.

Steps:

1. **Group all objects** of your logo.

[image]

2. Create a **New shape that cover all the Part** that you want to display in your logo

[image]

3. **Select both Logo and shape > Right click and select clipping mask** from Drop-down menu

[image]

You can always release the clipping mask and can edit your logo.
Fast and Easy!